# How to reach the private xsd file by using a URL in "schemaLocation" to validate the xml file

Tags: xml, gitlab, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate the xml files with a xsd file. The xsd file is in my branch of a private repository in GitLab.

part of the xsd file shows like:
...
<xsd:import namespace="schema.xsd" schemaLocation="https://https://gitlab.com/username/repository/-/raw/branch/path/to/schema.xsd?private_token=MY_TOKEN"/>
...

The error shows:
Java exception occurred:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;systemId:https://gitlab/users/sign_in ; lineNumber:5; columnNumber:24;s4s-elt-character:Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Sign in GitLab'.

Is anyone know why the error shows up and have a solution to it? Thanks!

Comment: Well it looks like the URL request to GitLab failed, or rather, resulted in a request to do some kind of authentication. Simplest solution would be to access the schema files from a local copy on your own machine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I am trying to do the pipeline tests in cloud for checking the xml files, is there another solution that I can reach the xsd file in my repository? I try to use the relative paths like "../../schema.xsd", but still failed.

Comment: Note: the extra `https://` in front of the URI looks spurious.

Comment: There may be a way of doing this, and the fact that you're adding a private_token to the URL suggests you're aware of some mechanism for getting past the authentication steps, but it's not something I can help you with.

Comment: All right, I am trying to find the original URL link online for this xsd file not from my repository,  still thank you for your help!